# Ways to Decentralize Oraclize

Tags: oracles

Based on my understanding, Oraclize is a centralized solution. What are some ways to decentralize Oraclize?

Answer (score 3):

You could look at some projects like Augur, which use betting markets to incentivize users to report the outcome of real world events, esentially creating a crowd source oracle on the blockchain.

https://www.augur.net/

Whitepaper: https://www.augur.net/whitepaper.pdf

Comment: Thanks -- is this a production ready system?

Comment: I believe it is currently in Beta on the Ethereum test net.

Answer (score 0):

By leveraging the proof-types Oraclize offer ([about which see here in the docs](http://docs.oraclize.it/#ethereum-quick-start-authenticity-proofs)) you can ameliorate much of the centralizing aspect of using an oracle service. This means that now you're only trusting the source you're requesting data from, but not the Oraclize service that is *retreiving* you that data.

Comment: That's not as true as the Oraclize documentation would have you believe. If code depends on Oraclize, then it will only allow oracle responses that come from a specific, hard-coded address, owned by Oraclize. If that address doesn't send the response, then your dapp is now broken.

Comment: You're absolutely correct about that centralizing aspect, which is something else that needs to be addressed by the developer. For example, not gating the Oraclize `__callback` function to _only_ the Oraclize address. Of course now you have another point of centralization too, which also needs to be managed. 

The exact same problem, however, persists whomever you're relying on to provide off chain data.

Answer (score 0):

google Towncrier/ChainLink, they are building decentralized oracles on intel SGX.

Going further down that road, I think hyperledger sawtooth could offer a basis for a true decentralized oracles blockchain network as they use a consensus system that is based on intel SGX. However not sure if there has been research done on this.

Nontheless the proof-of-authenticity of OraclizeIt is a good start, if it truly works that is. I haven't checked it.

http://www.town-crier.org/
https://www.smartcontract.com/link

Comment: Thanks -- is this a production ready system?

Comment: I don't think anything regarding blockchain / DLT is really production ready as we speak